# Spherical-Coordinate Reference Frame

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates

my problem looks apparently easy but I can figure out a solution. I'm going through a paper about the Boltzmann equation and I got stuck with this change of coordinates. The original formula for Q (it's the collision integral but that is not relevant at the moment) is the following:

$$
Q(f,f)(v) = \int\limits_{x\in{B_{R}}} \;\int\limits_{y\in{B_{R}}} \delta(x\cdot{y}) K(|x|,|y|)[f(v+x)f(v+y)-f(v+x+y)f(v)]dxdy\,.
$$

Just to let you know, f is a probability distribution and $K$ is the so-called kernel. $ \delta $ is the Dirac delta as one might guess. $ B_{R} $ is the ball of radius $R$ centered in the origin, $d$ is the dimension of $x$ and $y$.

By a change of coordinates, namely $ x=\rho e $ and $ y=\rho' e' $, I "should" get

$$
Q(f,f)(v) = \frac{1}{4} \int\limits_{e\in{\Bbb S^{d-1}}} \; \int\limits_{e'\in{\Bbb S^{d-1}}} \int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-R}^{R} \rho^{d-2} \rho'^{d-2} \delta(e\cdot{e'}) K(\rho,\rho')[f(v+\rho'e')f(v+\rho e)-f(v+\rho e+\rho'e')f(v)]d\rho d\rho'dede'\,.
$$

Here $ \Bbb S^{d-1} $ denotes the sphere of unitary radius centered in the origin of dimension $d-1$.

The integral makes perfectly sense and I tried to compute it directly in one case and the two expressions yield the very same result. By applying the usual change of coordinates for an $n$-sphere (same formula as the one given by Wikipedia on the $n$-sphere article) and by substituting the angles by the surface element after having computed the determinant of the Jacobian, I get the same result except for the exponent of $ \rho $. I get $ \rho^{d-1} \rho'^{d-1} $ instead of $ \rho^{d-2} \rho'^{d-2} $.

Then I tried to solve the problem by considering a single vector made up by the two column vectors $x$ and $y$ (the dimension of the problem is doubled) to see whether I could get the right exponent but I couldn't. Could you please suggest a strategy to get that formula (or a reference)? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that $\rho$ and $\rho'$ should go from $-R$ to $+R$ ? If this is a radius, shouldn't it be reduced to $[0 \,, R]$ ? Concerning the exponent of $\rho$, the expected exponent is $d - 1$ and not $d - 2$, because of an homogeneity (dimensions) argument. One has $[dx] \sim L^{d} \sim \rho ^{d-1} d \rho $, where $[\,]$ is the *unit* (or physical dimension) of the quantity.

Comment: Jibe, thanks for your answer. I agree with you, the exponent should be d-1 but I don't know why all the references give d-2. As far as the radius is concerned, the domain is extended and the final result is dived by four (see the fraction before the integral sign). Unfortunately, this same formula is cited with d-2 as an exponent by several papers based on this one.

Comment: The reason why the exponent is $d-2$ is because the quantity $e$ also has the dimension of a length.

Comment: GFR, thanks. Anyway the radius of the sphere S is one. That would work out if the radius were $ \rho $. Is my reasoning wrong? Anyway, in strictly dimensional terms, that works. But the quantity $ e $ does not vary "in length", so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Nope you are right, sorry, I got confused by the notation, I guess in the second integral you mean $ e\in S ^{ d-1 } $, not $x$.  Anyway, the reason is that on power of $\rho$ is eaten up by the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice than in the second integral you have $\delta(e\cdot e^\prime)$ and not $\delta(\rho e\cdot \rho^\prime e^\prime)$. But in fact
$\delta(\rho e\cdot \rho^\prime e^\prime)=\frac{1}{\rho\rho^\prime}\delta( e\cdot  e^\prime)$ thus explaining the powers of $\rho$ you are missing.

Comment: Sorry, I've just corrected it. It's my fault. Your explanation is clear. I just completely forgot the property of scaling of the Dirac delta! Would you believe it if I told you I spent a day on it looking for the properties of the Kernel? Great. Thanks GFR and everyone. Have a good day.